# New Terminal bash file error

Tags: 14.04, bash

Upon opening a new terminal in Ubuntu, I get this error. I tried opening the bashrc file but It seems to be empty.

```
bash: /home/rma/prac/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/rma/trials/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory   
bash: /home/rma/T/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/rma/abc/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/rma/RMP/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
$
```

I am running ROS Jade on Ubuntu 14.04

I had old workspaces which I deleted following the information given [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/105576/catkin-moveremove-package-and-workspace/). I think there was something left which wasn't removed with the workspaces.

What could be the error and how can I solve it?

Any suggestions or comments will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `bash -x`, so that you can see what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with gedit.

`gedit ~/.bashrc` brought up the bashrc file from which I was able to remove those lines. Upon saving and opening a new terminal, I could see no such lines.